# Effect on angular width of central bright fringe

Tags: visible-light, diffraction, quantum-optics, wavelength

In a single slit experiment when the light of a smaller wavelength is used what happens to the angular width of central bright fringe?

Comment: Which books and internet articles have you consulted?

Comment: @PhilipWood it's kind of class lecture where I got this confusion.. I have only consulted some south Asian academic books.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with those books? Have you looked up $diffraction$? Any textbook that deals with diffraction, even in an elementary way, should discuss how the extent of spreading depends on $\frac{\text{wavelength}}{\text{gap width}}.$

Comment: @PhilipWood thanks a lot..could never get a better answer!!!!!!!